# Upgrade/update yt-dlp via pip?

Tags: pip, yt-dlp

There used to be a top answer with a simple command to update yt-dlp via pip, and I swore it was `pip install --upgrade yt-dlp`, but maybe it was `python3 pip install --upgrade yt-dlp`. I cannot test it locally so I have to ask: I am being told there is an error that `-u does not exist` when my command is typed out~.

We are on `termbin` via F-Droid.

This error was caused by a syntax error:
`-upgrade` was used instead of `--upgrade`.

Comment: We can't go with hearsay. Please show us these commands and their outputs as when they were run.

Comment: Will update when I can get the terminal info from the user, today.

Comment: In the future, please add the -vU output to the yt-dlp command when tracking outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/Installation#with-pip
According to this, my command is correct. The error: "`ERROR: [youtube] Unable to extract uploader id`" is known. New version will be released soon.

Comment: Although the other answers are useful, essentially the source of my problem was very specific.  **When new versions are being released, sometimes there is downtime: update will not work and the current version will not work.**

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you installed it.

If you installed it via pip, use:

```
pip install --upgrade yt-dlp
```

otherwise use:

```
yt-dlp -U
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   yt-dlp -U
```

to update if you are using the release binaries

Comment: Your answer may get deleted.  To avoid it, please edit and explain what the options mean.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see tne [guidelines for answering](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776958/edit) your question accordingly to prevent deletion.

Comment: This answer is non-working if you initially install yt-dlp via pip, which might be why it was deleted. Please use the correct test environments when testing.